# Hadoop installation with cygwin: unable to execute the start-dfs.sh script

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cygwin

I am trying to install hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0 cluster on my desktop with windows 8 using cygwin.
I am getting some error while trying to run the command ./sbin/start-dfs.sh
The stack trace is-

```
$ ./sbin/start-dfs.sh
cygpath: can't convert empty path
which: no hdfs in (./C:\cygwin64\usr\local\hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/bin)
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
C:\cygwin64\usr\local\hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/bin/hdfs: line 24: /usr/local/hadoop                                                                                                                -2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/../libexec/hdfs-config.sh: No such file or directory
cygpath: can't convert empty path
C:\cygwin64\usr\local\hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/bin/hdfs: line 172: exec: : not foun                                                                                                                d
Starting namenodes on []
cygpath: can't convert empty path
cygpath: can't convert empty path
localhost: bash: line 0: cd: C:cygwin64usrlocalhadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0: No such fi                                                                                                                le or directory
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
cygpath: can't convert empty path
cygpath: can't convert empty path
localhost: bash: line 0: cd: C:cygwin64usrlocalhadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0: No such fi                                                                                                                le or directory
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
which: no hdfs in (./C:\cygwin64\usr\local\hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/bin)
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
C:\cygwin64\usr\local\hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/bin/hdfs: line 24: /usr/local/hadoop                                                                                                                -2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/../libexec/hdfs-config.sh: No such file or directory
cygpath: can't convert empty path
C:\cygwin64\usr\local\hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/bin/hdfs: line 172: exec: : not foun                                                                                                                d
```

Please suggest a solution